# IE10 - CSS animation not working

Tags: animation, css, internet-explorer-10

I have a scale animation that worked in IE10 for about a day and then stopped. I didn't make any changes and am not sure what would happen to break it.

Does anyone have any ideas? When I look in the IE dev tools it's not picking up the animation name, but is picking up all the other properties.

Here's the CSS:

```
@-ms-keyframes move97
{
    0% {
        transform:scale(1,1);
        -ms-transform:scale(1,1); 
        -moz-transform:scale(1,1); 
        -webkit-transform:scale(1,1); 
        -o-transform:scale(1,1); 
    }
    50% {
        transform:scale(0.97,0.97);
        -ms-transform:scale(0.97,0.97); 
        -moz-transform:scale(0.97,0.97); 
        -webkit-transform:scale(0.97,0.97); 
        -o-transform:scale(0.97,0.97); 
    }
    100% {
        transform:scale(1,1);
        -ms-transform:scale(1,1); 
        -moz-transform:scale(1,1); 
        -webkit-transform:scale(1,1); 
        -o-transform:scale(1,1); 
    }
}

.press97
{
    -ms-animation-name: move97 0.2s; /* note MS has this different.... ugh */
    animation: move97 0.2s;
    -moz-animation: move97 0.2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: move97 0.2s; /* Safari and Chrome */ 

    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;   

    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Might I ask why you're using non-IE vendor extensions inside a `@-ms-keyframes` block which is very clearly only read by IE?

Comment: I was copying and pasting inside the stylesheet and hadn't bothered to tidy that up.

Comment: You should also always end your property list with the standards according unprefixed one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the help link I was following isn't correct. When I change it to -ms-animation: move97 0.2s, it works. This is what I had originally and it did NOT work, so I changed it to what's shown above, which did.

Help link I followed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/hh673530.aspx

I've been told it'll be corrected.

Answer (score 19):

The standard syntax is [supported in Internet Explorer 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453858.aspx) with no need for the `-ms` prefix on the keyframes declaration, nor on the `animation-name` property. In fact, IE10, like the other vendor products, supports the shorthand `animation` property alone as well:

```css
@keyframes myanimation {
    0%   { color: black; }
    80%  { color: gold; transform: translate(20px,20px); }
    100% { color: black; translate(0,0); }
}

#anim {
    display: inline-block;
    animation: myanimation 5s 5; /* use myanimation 5s duration, 5 times */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfJ4Z/1/

Comment: media queries can block IE from seeing keyframe animations too.

Comment: I pulled my keyframes out to their own file instead of having them in my media-query-wrapped components and it fixed it. Thanks Graham