# Pure CSS using keyframes animation refuses to animate

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to create a pure CSS animation (fade in/fade out with timer) without the use of jQuery. When I check on IE10 and IE11 the animation doesn't work. On Firefox, Safari, and Chrome it works perfectly.

How can I get this to also work in IE10 and 11?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="cf">
    <div>
        <img class="bottom" src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" title="Image 1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class="top" src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" title="Image 2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:550px;
  width:600px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  45%   { opacity: 1; }
  55%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  45%   { opacity: 1; }
  55%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  45%   { opacity: 1; }
  55%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  45%   { opacity: 1; }
  55%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  45%   { opacity: 1; }
  55%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

#cf img.top {
    animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation: cf3FadeInOut 6s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate; 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE10 - CSS animation not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355411/ie10-css-animation-not-working)

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D thanks for the link. I have checked and found out I was missing some lines of CSS code, which I have updated but the fade in/fade out is still not working with IE10+.

Answer (score 0):

My updated CSS code now is below, which is still not working on IE10+ but this has been tested in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and still working.

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:550px;
  width:600px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
 0%   { filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1; -khtml-opacity:1; opacity: 1; }
 45%   { filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1; -khtml-opacity:1; opacity: 1; }
 55%   { filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; -khtml-opacity:0; opacity: 0; }
 100% { filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; -khtml-opacity:0; opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
 0%   { filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1; -khtml-opacity:1; opacity: 1; }
 45%   { filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1; -khtml-opacity:1; opacity: 1; }
 55%   { filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; -khtml-opacity:0; opacity: 0; }
 100% { filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; -khtml-opacity:0; opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
 0%   { filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1; -khtml-opacity:1; opacity: 1; }
 45%   { filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1; -khtml-opacity:1; opacity: 1; }
 55%   { filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; -khtml-opacity:0; opacity: 0; }
 100% { filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; -khtml-opacity:0; opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
 0%   { filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1; -khtml-opacity:1; opacity: 1; }
 45%   { filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1; -khtml-opacity:1; opacity: 1; }
 55%   { filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; -khtml-opacity:0; opacity: 0; }
 100% { filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; -khtml-opacity:0; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
 0%   { filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1; -khtml-opacity:1; opacity: 1; }
 45%   { filter: alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1; -khtml-opacity:1; opacity: 1; }
 55%   { filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; -khtml-opacity:0; opacity: 0; }
 100% { filter: alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; -khtml-opacity:0; opacity: 0; }
}


#cf img.top {
    animation: cf3FadeInOut 6s;
    -ms-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut 6s;
    -moz-animation: cf3FadeInOut 6s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: cf3FadeInOut 6s; /* Safari and Chrome */ 

    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    animation-direction: alternate;
    -ms-animation-direction: alternate;  
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```