# CSS animation not working in all versions of IE

Tags: html, css

My animations are fine in Firefox and Chrome but not IE10 /11 . I also tried using `0%` and `100%` instead of `from` and `to`

EDIT: Apologies, just to clarify the problem. The animation is moving as intented as per the CSS rules above both in Chrome and Firefox. However to put it simply, nothing is happening in Internet Explorer, the objects are staying exactly where they are

```
.object-left-side.move { 

    -webkit-animation: .75s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running move_left;
    -moz-animation: .75s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running move_left;
    -o-animation: .75s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running move_left;
    -ms-animation: .75s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running move_left;
    animation: .75s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running move_left;

 }

@-webkit-keyframes move_left {
     from { left: 50%;top:24%;} 
     to {left:5%;top:48%;} 
}

@keyframes move_left {
     from { left: 50%;top:24%;} 
     to {left:5%;top:48%;} 
}
 @-moz-keyframes move_left {
     from { left: 50%;top:24%;} 
     to {left:5%;top:48%;} 
}

 @-ms-keyframes move_left {
     from { left: 50%;top:24%;} 
     to {left:5%;top:48%;} 
}

 @-o-keyframes move_left {
     from { left: 50%;top:24%;} 
     to {left:5%;top:48%;} 
}

.object-left-side {

  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete example, that actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: sorry, a bit more added, but overall the problem is basically that nothing is happening with the animation on Internet Explorer

Comment: Have you searched for similar questions, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355411/ie10-css-animation-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#the_ms_animation_property),

> The animation property values must be set in the following order:
>   animation-name
>   animation-duration
>   animation-timing-function
>   animation-delay
>   animation-iteration-count
>   animation-direction

So, in other words, if you write

```css
animation: move_left .75s ease 0s 1 forwards;
```

it will work in IE11.

```css
.object-left-side.move {
  -webkit-animation: .75s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running move_left;
  -moz-animation: .75s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running move_left;
  -o-animation: .75s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running move_left;
  -ms-animation: .75s ease 0s normal forwards 1 running move_left;
  animation: move_left .75s ease 0s 1 forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move_left {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    top: 24%;
  }
  to {
    left: 5%;
    top: 48%;
  }
}
@keyframes move_left {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    top: 24%;
  }
  to {
    left: 5%;
    top: 48%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes move_left {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    top: 24%;
  }
  to {
    left: 5%;
    top: 48%;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes move_left {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    top: 24%;
  }
  to {
    left: 5%;
    top: 48%;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes move_left {
  from {
    left: 50%;
    top: 24%;
  }
  to {
    left: 5%;
    top: 48%;
  }
}
.object-left-side {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="object-left-side move">Test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I didnt realise the order was important, that fixed it!