# Animation issues with internet explorer

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to make waves with continuously floating animation. I have put the code below that I have tried and it's working fine in all browsers except internet explorer.

Is there anything to do with this code to make it work in explorer? Please help. 
 If you need anything else please let me know. Thanks.

```css
.inf-waveWrapperInner {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: auto;
}

.inf-bgTop {
  height: 188px;
  bottom: 130px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.inf-bgMiddle {
  height: 255px;
  bottom: 5px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.inf-bgBottom {
  height: 170px;
}

.inf-wave {
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat no-repeat !important;
  background-position: 0 top;
  transform-origin: center top;
}

.inf-wave.inf-waveTop {
  animation: move_wave 25s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: move_wave 25s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.inf-wave.inf-waveMiddle {
  animation: move_wave 25s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: move_wave 25s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.inf-wave.inf-waveBottom {
  animation: move_wave 25s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: move_wave 25s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  &::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: #0B5268;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move_wave {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-25%) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-25%) translateZ(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0)
  }
}

@keyframes move_wave {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-25%) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-25%) translateZ(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inf-waveWrapperInner inf-bgTop">
  <div class="inf-wave inf-waveTop" style="background:url(images/inf-wave-one.svg);"></div>
</div>
<div class="inf-waveWrapperInner inf-bgMiddle">
  <div class="inf-wave inf-waveMiddle" style="background:url(images/inf-wave-two.svg);"></div>
</div>
<div class="inf-waveWrapperInner inf-bgBottom">
  <div class="inf-wave inf-waveBottom" style="background:url(images/inf-wave-three.svg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE10 - CSS animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355411/ie10-css-animation-not-working)