# size of image varies in Chrome and IE 11

Tags: html, css

http://www.cupiros.com/rental-long.html

as for the coffee machine images on this web page, the size of the image varies in Chrome and IE11. image resizing is working well with chrome, but in IE 11 the images are out of the full screen. Does anyone have the idea? It's my first work so please understand that I'm not aware of the HTML.

- size of each image: 287*287
- using bootstrap

Here are my CSS and HTML code.

```
/*tab*/
@import url(//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font awesome.min.css);
body { padding-top: 0px; }
.nav.nav-justified > li > a { position: relative; }
.nav.nav-justified > li > a:hover,
.nav.nav-justified > li > a:focus { background-color: transparent; }
.nav.nav-justified > li > a > .quote {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #13c0ba;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    color: #fff;  
}
.nav.nav-justified > li.active > a > .quote { opacity: 1; }
.nav.nav-justified > li > a > img { box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #13c0ba; }
.nav.nav-justified > li > a > img { 
    max-width: 100%; 
    opacity: 0.7;  
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8,0.8); 
        transform: scale(0.8,0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
        transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.nav.nav-justified > li.active > a > img,
.nav.nav-justified > li:hover > a > img,
.nav.nav-justified > li:focus > a > img { 
    opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transform: none;  
        transform: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);     
        transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
    .tab-pane .tab-inner { padding: 30px 0 20px; }     
    @media (min-width: 768px) {                                   
    .nav.nav-justified > li > a > .quote {
        left: auto;
        top: auto;
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 0px;
    }  
}
/*tab 끝*/
```

```
  <!--col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3-->
        <div class="[ col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ]">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="[ nav nav-justified ]" id="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="">
                    <a href="#anna" aria-controls="anna" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        <img class="img-rounded" src="images/CM1004_right.jpg" />
                        <!--
                        <span class="quote"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
                        -->
                        <p><br>< CM1004 ></p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="">
                    <a href="#daksh" aria-controls="daksh" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        <img class="img-rounded" src="images/베누스타_right.jpg" />
                        <!--
                        <span class="quote"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
                      -->
                        <p><br>< VENUSTA - HQ ></p>
                    </a>
                </li>
               <li role="presentation" class="">
                    <a href="#new" aria-controls="new" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        <img class="img-rounded" src="images/F11_right.jpg" />
                        <!--
                        <span class="quote"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
                      -->
                        <p><br>< Dr.Coffee - F11 ></p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="">
                    <a href="#dustin" aria-controls="dustin" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        <img class="img-rounded" src="images/가찌아_right.png" />   <!--원본이미지 파일 (128*128) "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/waferbaby/128.jpg"-->
                        <!--
                        <span class="quote"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
                        -->
                        <p><br>< GAGGIA - 싱크로니로직 ></p>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems normal transition and scaling properties does not work with IE.

Try this - it worked for me

In your following properties :

```
.nav-justified.nav > li.active > a > img, .nav-justified.nav > li:hover > a > img, .nav-justified.nav > li:focus > a > img
```

Along with

`transform: none; transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);`

add following code

`-ms-transform : none;-ms-animation: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);`

For explaination Check this out:

- **[Microsoft documentation for animation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/hh673530(v=vs.85))**
- **[Usage of Animation properties for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355411/ie10-css-animation-not-working)**

Comment: Now the animation is working!  Do you know how to change image size and alignment like a Chrome browser ? I want to center the images.

Comment: In `.nav-justified.nav > li > a > img` property for property max-width instead of **%** use **rem** unit . I tried this and works well : `max-width:20rem`